# Way to SELECT all rows where specified value is present, without specifying columns names?

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is a way to formulate a query to select all rows where a certain value is present, without specifying columns names?

ex. SELECT * FROM table WHERE "any column" = 2;

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in SQL. You would have to write something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 2 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...)
```

You could construct this query dynamically using the information in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, so you could do it in a stored procedure.